# The operation could not be performed (using a LINKED-SERVER in Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, linked-server

I'm trying to perform a update query in a database located in a remote server through a LINKED SERVER connection. I'm already tested and works fine when use SGBD.

In my web app, I have hibernate 3.5 and, when try to use it to execute the query, I'm faced with the following error message:

*"The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "XYZ" was unable to begin a distributed transaction"*

Although, if try use pure JDBC, works fine.

Whats the hibernate's problem with externals access?